# запускаю этот код и сразу закрывается

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import random
import sqlite3

layout1 = [
    [sg.text('Что нужно сделать')],
    [sg.button('Работа с базой')],
    [sg.button('Чекер прокси')]
]

layout2 = [
    [sg.Text('Загрузить базу'), sg.InputText(key='-BAZA-'), sg.FileBrowse()],
    [sg.text('Выберите что нужно сделать')],
    [sg.button('Убрать ссылки')],
]

layout3 = [
    [sg.text('Чекер прокси')]
]

layout = [[sg.Column(layout1, key='-COL1-'), sg.Column(layout2, visible=False, key='-COL2-'), sg.Column(layout3, visible=False, key='-COL3-')],
          [sg.Button('Работа с базой'), sg.Button('Чекер прокси'), sg.Button('Выход')]]

window = sg.Window('Dynamic Window', layout)

layout = 1

while True:                             # The Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    # print(event, values) #debug
    if event in (None, 'Выход'):
        break
    if event == ('Работа с базой'):
        print(layout)
        window[f'-COL{layout}-'].update(visible=False)            
        if layout < 3:
            layout += 1 
            window[f'-COL{layout}-'].update(visible=True)
        else:
            window[f'-COL3-'].update(visible=True)
    elif event == 'Чекер прокси':
         window[f'-COL{layout}-'].update(visible=False)
         window[f'-COL1-'].update(visible=True)
         layout = 1
window.close()
```

Запускаю этот код, открывается черное окно и сразу закрывается, в idle выдает ошибку с синтаксисом

Comment: Не дублируйте вопрос несколько раз. Если нужно внести дополнение в вопрос, отредактируйте его. Редактирование также поднимает вопрос на главной странице.